# Is it possible to export all movie clips as images from actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

You can manually save some particular movie clip on a stage as an image by running "Export > Export Image". Is it possible to write an actionscript that would export all movie clips on a stage to images automatically? Or at least is there a way to automate this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [as3corelib](http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) which comes with a JPGEncoder and a PNGEncoder, and checking out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799784/how-to-export-image-from-swf-with-actionscript3-php) for information on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A [JSFL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_ExtendingFlash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fe8.html) script could help here. It allows you to automate/script most things you can do manually in the Flash IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this library: [Flash to PNG Export](http://www.flashiology.com/component/content/article/51-flash-to-png-jpeg-exporter-class-actionscript-3.html), works pretty good.