# How to Generate image of a rendered SWF file in HTML web page using Action Script?

Tags: actionscript

I have to generate an Image(snap shot) out of a rendered SWF file in HTML web page and have to save the same image in server. Is it possible by using ActionScript and if so pls guide me with some sample code snippets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question looks pretty relevant to what you are trying to achieve:

[How to export image from swf with ActionScript3/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799784/how-to-export-image-from-swf-with-actionscript3-php)