# AS3 Save Media File to server

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, record

im not good with as3 and was wondering if someone could help me with this seeing as I cant find the answer on google.

I currently have this

> fileReference.save(recorder.output,
>   "recordedfile.wav");

How would I change that so **recorder.output** saves to my server in the same directory instead of how it is now, which produces a file save window to save on my local hard drive.

Comment: Do you mean save on the webserver? AS3 runs on the client only.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to send your bytearray to some server-side script that will save it on your server.

Similar question was answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597947/how-can-i-send-a-bytearray-from-flash-and-some-form-data-to-php)

I think the best way to achieve what you want is using [URLRequestWrapper class by Jonathan Marston.](http://code.google.com/p/asfeedback/source/browse/trunk/com/marston/utils/URLRequestWrapper.as?spec=svn4&r=4) It is well commented so it should be easy to use.
If you are using php you can read on how to receive and save a file [on php.net.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)