# convert masked movieclip into bitmap and save it on server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i have a 
dsgnArea----> a movieclip

dsgnArea is masked by dsgnAreaMask, which inturn is a movieclip

dsgnArea.mask=dsgnAreaMask;

the width,height and position of dsgnAreaMask and dsgnArea are same.

i dynamically added multiple movieclips and labels to dsgnArea;
like..
       dsgnArea.addChild(movieClip1);
       dsgnArea.addChild(movieClip2);
       dsgnArea.addChild(label1);
       dsgnArea.addChild(label2); and so on...

```
       these movieclips (movieClip1,movieClip2,......) and labels(label1,label2,....) positions can be altered in runtime..
```

but as i masked the dsgnArea with dsgnAreaMask, only a portion of the added movieClips and labels are visible...

So, my problem is to grab that visible portion in dsgnArea into a bitmap,like a screenshot of that particular dsgnArea, and save it in my server.

please help me out in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `s` is the DisplayObject object you want to capture and `m` is the mask applied on it.

```
var maskRect:Rectangle = m.getRect(s);
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -maskRect.x, -maskRect.y);

var w:Number = Math.min(s.width, maskRect.right) - maskRect.x;
var h:Number = Math.min(s.height, maskRect.bottom) - maskRect.y;

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h);
bd.draw(s, matrix);
```

Does that work?

Comment: hey mj. this is not working with masked movie clips,but its fine with unmasked movieclips..

Answer (score 0):

The [BitmapData draw](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) method is what you are looking for. You can use it's clipRect param to define what you would like to draw (the masked parts).

Answer (score 0):

[Quasimondo](http://www.quasimondo.com/) did a handy little method to do this (take a snapshot of the whole displayObject), it's available here:  http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000670.php

I don't know if it works with masked content though.
if it doesn't, the trick would be to translate the whole content by the size of the mask

```
var bounds:Rectangle = dsgnAreaMask.getBounds( dsgnAreaMask );
```

instead of using the content of the clip

```
var bounds:Rectangle = clip.getBounds( clip );
```

as far as saving file to server is concerned, the question was asked (answered?) here  [AS3 Save Media File to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635820/as3-save-media-file-to-server)