# Starling and cameraroll upload type coercion

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I am trying to implement the cameraUI here
[Upload Library or captured images on iOS with Flex Mobile 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913974/upload-library-or-captured-images-on-ios-with-flex-mobile-4-6)

in my starling project to allow a user to select an image and upload to a server but I am getting an error:

```
Error #1034: Type coercion failed: cannot convert starling.events::Event@752c0d1 to flash.events.Event
```

Looks like is the culprit:

```
private function imageSelected( event:MediaEvent ):void
    {
        trace( "Media selected..." );   

        var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
        dataSource = imagePromise.open();    
        if( imagePromise.isAsync )
        {
            trace("Asynchronous media promise.");
            var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher;            
            eventSource.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded);         
        } else {
            trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
            readMediaData();
        }
    }
```

I am using Starling to utilise Feathers UI.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both flash events and starling events imported? Make sure you pass the starling event to the onMediaLoaded function.
So:

```
function onMediaLoaded(event:starling.events.Event){
   //do stuff
}
```

not:

```
function onMediaLoaded(event:Event){
   //do stuff
}
```