# Upload loader.loaderInfo.byte

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, image-uploading

I am trying to upload images using ByteArray from a mobile app.

The source image data needs to be loaded using Loader class(loadFilePromise). When I tried to upload loader.loaderInfo.byte using URLRequestWrapper, it couldn't generate the correct image on the server side.

When I inspect the data, I noticed the data size is different from the actual generated image file on the device.

**loader.loaderInfo.byte**

> bytesAvailable  19008 [0x4a40]
> endian  "bigEndian"
> length  19008 [0x4a40]
> objectEncoding  3
> position    0

**binary image data loaded through URLLoader**

> bytesAvailable  18946 [0x4a02]  
> endian  "bigEndian" 
> length  18946 [0x4a02]  
> objectEncoding  3   
> position    0

Is it possible to upload image data through loader.loaderInfo.byte? If so, how?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: check this question and the answers out, it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913974/upload-library-or-captured-images-on-ios-with-flex-mobile-4-6