# Flex & PHP - Send email attachment

Tags: php, flex4, flash-builder, email-attachments

I'ld like for my visitor to be able to send an email to a friend with the creation from my application as an attatchment (so like a screencap of the creation). I can get Flex and PHP to communicate and send an email, but I can't get the image to send. It sends an attachment that is 2o or less and can't be opened (of course !).

I don't get an error return from my application

I found these posts linked below which helped me, but I still don't get how to pass the image from Flex to PHP.

- [Saving entire Flash document as JPEG to email as an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864606/saving-entire-flash-document-as-jpeg-to-email-as-an-attachment)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266284/sending-an-e-mail-with-attachment-with-php-from-flex

Here is my code from Flex :

```
private function sendMail():void{
            var _nomSTF:String = nomSTF.text;
            var _emailSTF:String = emailSTF.text;
            var _emailFriendSTF:String = emailFriendSTF.text;
            var _sujetSTF:String = sujetSTF.text;
            var _messageSTF:String = messageSTF.text;

            //IMAGE
            var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
            var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();

            var screenshotData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(conteneurDeMonImage.width, conteneurDeMonImage.height, true, 0xFFFFFF);

            screenshotData.draw(conteneurDeMonImage);
            //var outputData:ByteArray = encoder.encode(screenshotData);
            //var base64:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
            var png:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
            byteArray = png.encode(screenshotData);

            //base64.encodeBytes(outputData);
            //FIN IMAGE


            var evValidMail:ValidationResultEvent = emailSTFValidator.validate();
            var evValidMailFriend:ValidationResultEvent = emailFriendSTFValidator.validate();
            var evValidName:ValidationResultEvent = nomSTFValidator.validate();

            if (evValidMail.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID
                && evValidName.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID
                && evValidMailFriend.type == ValidationResultEvent.VALID){
                emailService.send({senderName: _nomSTF, senderEmail:_emailSTF, emailFriendSTF: _emailFriendSTF,
                    emailSubject:_sujetSTF, emailMessage: _messageSTF, file : byteArray});
            } else {
                resultLabel.text="There are Form errors";
                resultLabel.setStyle("styleName", "invalid");
            }
        }

        private function emailResultSTF():void{
            Alert.show("Votre message a bien été envoyé");
            containerSendToFriend.visible = false;
        }
<fx:Declarations>

    <s:HTTPService id="emailService" url="src/mail.php" method="POST"
                    resultFormat="xml" useProxy="false"
                    result="emailResultSTF()"
                    fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail + '\n' + event.message.toString())"/>

</fx:Declarations>
```

And here's my PHP code :

```
$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; 
$fileatt_name = "baignoireElyseeConcept.png";
$sender_name =  $_POST['senderName'];
$email_from = $_POST['senderEmail']; 
$email_subject = $_POST['emailSubject'];  
$email_message = $_POST['emailMessage'];  

$email_to = $_POST['emailFriendSTF']; 

$headers = 'From:'.$sender_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';   

$data= $_POST['file'];

$semi_rand = md5(time());   
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";   

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .   
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .   
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";   

$email_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .   
                "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .   
                "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" .   
               "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .   
$email_message . "\n\n";   


$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .   
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .   
                  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .   
                 $data . "\n\n" .   
                  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";   

$mailsend = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Marie

Comment: What does "an attachment that is 2o or less" mean? Specifically, what is '2o'?

Comment: It's 2 octets. I don't know how the file size can vary but it does sometimes... the file I should get would be about 200-300ko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked around for an answer for this for days and finally got it to work so here's how I did it (helped by a lot of ressources on the internet and specifically this one : http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html)

here's my Flex code for my image :

```
var je:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100); 

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(conteneurDeMonImage.width,conteneurDeMonImage.height);
bd.draw(conteneurDeMonImage);

var ba:ByteArray = je.encode(bd);

var be:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
be.encodeBytes(ba);

var encodedData:String = be.toString();

            // Testing if my base64 is working in FLEX
            /*var byteArr:ByteArray;
            var B64dec:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
            B64dec.decode(encodedData);
            byteArr = B64dec.toByteArray();
            imageEnGrand.load(byteArr);*/

emailService.send({senderName: _nomSTF, senderEmail:_emailSTF, emailFriendSTF: _emailFriendSTF, emailSubject:_sujetSTF, emailMessage: _messageSTF, file : encodedData});
```

Here's my PHP code :

```
$fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream"; 
$fileatt_name = "test.jpg"; 

$sender_name =  $_POST['senderName'];
$email_from = $_POST['senderEmail']; 
$email_subject = $_POST['emailSubject'];  
$email_message = $_POST['emailMessage'];  

$email_to = $_POST['emailFriendSTF']; 

$headers = 'From:'.$sender_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';   

$data = $_POST['file'];

$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);

$img_data = base64_decode($data);
$png = chunk_split(base64_encode(($img_data)));

$semi_rand = md5(time());   
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";   

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"."Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n"." boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";   

$email_message =
                "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n".
                "--{$mime_boundary}\n"."Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n".
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".$email_message."\n\n";

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .   
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .   
                  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .   
                 $png . "\n\n" .   
                  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";   

$mailsend = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

I hope it helps someone who has the same problem as me !