# action script 3 Json request

Tags: ruby, json, actionscript-3, request

I am trying to send an image to a server with as3. 
I need the url of the hosted image back so i can share it to facebook and twitter. 
I was told to replicate what I have here in ruby code but cant quite make it.
Here is what i have.

Ruby code:

```
 require 'rest_client' # gem: rest-client
 require 'json'

 mcz_url = 'server URL'

 mcz_response = nil

 File.open(ARGV[0], 'r') do |f|
 params = { :file => f, :type => 'image', :sizes => nil }

   RestClient.post(mcz_url, params) do |response, request, result|
   mcz_response = response
  end
end

 unless mcz_response.nil?
   json = JSON.parse(mcz_response)
   puts "CDN Url: #{json['original']}"
else
  puts 'MCZ response is null'
end
```

Action script 3

```
  share_pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, publish); //buton to share a pic

  function publish(evt:MouseEvent):void {
var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (stage.width, 256);
    jpgSource.draw(stage);
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(90);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource); //image
trace("sharing pic...");
var request = new URLRequest("Server URL");

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;  
var messages:Array = new Array ();
    messages.push ({field_name:"file:", value: jpgSource});
    messages.push ({field_name:"type", value:"'image'"});
    messages.push ({field_name:"sizes", value:"nil"});

var vars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.data = JSON.stringify(messages);
request.data = vars;
trace("vars= "+vars);
trace ("request= "+request);
trace("done");


var linkGenerated:String = "";//image string i would like to get from the JSON
    var linkFace:String = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="
var linkShare:String = linkFace + linkGenerated ;
var requestFace = new URLRequest(linkShare);
navigateToURL(requestFace,"_blank");
```

}

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use [URLLoader.load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#load%28%29), and might be good to note FileReference.upload() for future needs. In both cases you'll need to split your publish function up using event listeners with handlers that will operate on the result once the server completes its process...

```
public function publish():void
{
    var urlToPost:URLRequest = new URLRequest("some_url_here");
    //attach any post data, etc.
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    //attach your event listeners, which will be called at some point in the future (asynchronous)
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
    //call load to start the upload
    urlLoader.load( urlToPost );
}

protected function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    var linkGenerated:String = urlLoader.data.some_image_string;//image string i would like to get from the JSON
    var linkFace:String = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="
    var linkShare:String = linkFace + linkGenerated ;
    var requestFace = new URLRequest(linkShare);
    navigateToURL(requestFace,"_blank");
}
```

A similar question/answer to what you are looking for can be [Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597947/how-can-i-send-a-bytearray-from-flash-and-some-form-data-to-php).

When using FileReference.upload() be sure to attach an event listener for DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA so that you can access any returned data from the server once the upload is complete.