# Images AS3 and JSON

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I asked this question before [action script 3 Json request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284162/action-script-3-json-request)

but it comes down to, how do i turn an image into a JSON object?

Thank you.

Comment: look up some Base64 encoder/decoder libraries. There are quite a few. It'll convert an image into a string that you can use in your JSON

Comment: Also, don't expect a quick answer - there was only three hours between your requests, and SO is worldwide, so some people who might want to answer your question are still fast asleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{
    // See http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/
    import by.blooddy.crypto.Base64;
    import by.blooddy.crypto.image.PNGEncoder;
    import by.blooddy.crypto.serialization.JSON;

    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class JsonImage extends Sprite
    {

        private var _loader : Loader = new Loader;

        public function JsonImage(){
            // Load an image
            _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onExternalImgLoaded);
            _loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"));
        }

        protected function onExternalImgLoaded(event:Event):void{
            trace("Google logo loaded");
            var json : String = encodeImageToJson(_loader.content);

            trace("Display from json : \n" + json);
            addChild( loadImageFromJson( json ) );
        }

        // encode an image to Json format
        public function encodeImageToJson(image : *) : String
        {
            var bd : BitmapData;

            // Check image type
            if(image is BitmapData)
                bd = image;
            else if(image is Bitmap)
                bd = (image as Bitmap).bitmapData;
            else if(image is DisplayObject)
            {
                bd = new BitmapData(DisplayObject(image).width, DisplayObject(image).height, true, 0);
                bd.draw(image);
            }else
                throw new Error ("Invalid image");

            // Encode to json
            return by.blooddy.crypto.serialization.JSON.encode({
                    image:
                        // Convert bytearray to String
                        Base64.encode(
                            // Make PNG bytearray from image
                            PNGEncoder.encode(bd)
                        )
                    });
        }

        // create a loader that will load an image embed in json
        public function loadImageFromJson(jsonData : String) : Loader
        {
            var l : Loader = new Loader;
            l.loadBytes(
                Base64.decode(
                    by.blooddy.crypto.serialization.JSON.decode(jsonData)["image"]));
            return l;
        }
    }
}
```